# How to get data FROM tableau?

Tags: excel, tableau-api

I have a bunch of data in Tableau. I'd like to get it into Excel.

Instead of making a report, then parsing that report, I'd like to hook Excel up directly to Tableau.

Tableau is grabbing data from a database, but due to "logic" we can't hook Excel up directly to the database... as easy as Excel makes it to do...

Is there a way to make an ODBC connection or some other power query connection directly from Excel to Tableau?

Comment: What "logic" issue prevents Excel from pulling in your data?  This sounds like an X/Y problem.  Also, Tableau is a BI visualization tool, so it's not typical to want to "connect" to it like a database to pull data in.  You'd be better off exporting from within Tableau to Excel, or connecting Excel directly to the database probably.

Comment: Where does your Tableau data come from?

Comment: @TimWilliams: It comes from a database that we're not allowed to pull from. Tableau is allowed to pull from it though. Annoying, I'd prefer to get the data direct from the horse's mouth, but I'll work with what I've got

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can export a view to a CSV by adding .csv to the URL. You can pass parameter values using query strings, but not filter values unfortunately.

`http://[Tableau Server Location]/views/[Workbook Name]/[View Name].csv?[Parameter Name]=[Value]&[Parameter Name]=[Value]`

A few things to note:

- Remove the spaces in your workbook name, view name, and parameter names. Special characters should also be removed, not url encoded.
- URL encode your parameter values
- You will get ALL of the fields from your view. This means your row, column, "detail", text label, and I believe caption values as well. If the same field is in your rows as well as text labels, it will show up twice on your exported CSV.
- Make sure to test your URL thoroughly before you use it, including changing your parameter values to make sure they are working too.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do that is to export the different sets individually. See example below:

[image]

Comment: Hey - I'm hoping to "pull" data from tableau, instead of "pushing" it